# Adding color to parts of text to be displayed in HTML

Tags: python, html, css, colors

I am trying to embed HTML tags in text that will be displayed in a text box.

I need to write text to a text box defined by:

```
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <p class="article-content"><small>{{ file_data }}</small></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

The pertinent css section is:

```
.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

I tried embedding HTML tags in the text from a python module, for example:

```
file_data += '<p style="color:red;">'+gedline+'</p>'
```

However, the HTML tags are not interpreted.  Instead they are printed verbatim.

```
<p style="color:red;">0 HEAD
</p><p style="color:red;">1 SOUR FTM
</p><p style="color:red;">0 @SUBM@ SUBM
</p><p style="color:red;">1 NAME Not Given
</p><p style="color:red;">0 @I13864@ INDI
</p><p style="color:red;">1 NAME Harry Clifton d/Murphy/
</p>
```

This is just an example.  Actually, I will be assigning different colors to various parts of each line, but the simple example above shows the problem.

Is there a better way to achieve my goals?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you describe more clearly the result you want to achieve, compared to the current result?

Answer (score 0):

In Django

1. The simplest way is to use the safe filter:

   {{ file_data | safe }}
2. You can also use autoescape tag

   {% autoescape off %}
   {{ file_data }}
   {% endautoescape %}

Comment: Thanks.  the "safe" filter works.  Now I'm getting unwanted side effects from the paragraph tag, like gaps between lines.    Also, I'll be changing the color of selected words within a sentence, and the paragraph tag creates a new line where it isn't wanted.  Is there an alternative to "<p" that doesn't cause these side effects?